# table.scrollleft is always zero

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with a fixed layout.  The columns take up more space than is available so a horizontal scroll bar appears.  Currently you can move around in the table using the keyboard arrows.  But when a cell is selected that is not in view I need to programmatically tell the scrollbar to move.  I thought this would be scrollleft but is not settable and is always zero.  Instead I have achieve my desired effect by using scrollIntoView(false).  This works but I still want to know why scrollleft was not working.

Answer (score -1):

Please see my fiddle. The function you may want to use is called `scrollLeft()`

http://jsfiddle.net/ydj5E/

jQuery Docs: http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollLeft

Comment: He just said `scrollLeft` isn't working for a table with fixed columns...
Also  your jsfiddle is using a static container instead of a table